# mpfr always crash R studio

Tags: r, mpfr

Second Update on Feb 22, 2021:

When running the codes in R outside RStudio:

```
> a <- mpfr(1:10, precBits=100)

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x10daa2bfb, cause 'illegal trap'

Traceback:
 1: mpfr.default(1:10, precBits = 100)
 2: mpfr(1:10, precBits = 100)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rmpfr_0.8-2 gmp_0.6-2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.4
```

---

Update on Feb 22, 2021:

R is updated to 4.0.4 and the issue is still there.

---

Added:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] OBsMD_6.1    Rmpfr_0.8-2  gmp_0.6-2    gtools_3.8.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

---

**- Update: It turns out that the same codes run well on my intel iMac,
but cannot run on my M1 Macbook. Any help that can make this run on
M1 is greatly appreciated!**

---

When I am running the following codes, my R Studio always crashes when I create the `a`. Does the same thing happen to you? Any help? Thanks!

```
library(gtools)
library(Rmpfr)
library(OBsMD)

DecimalDigits=10^4

a <- mpfr(c(1:10), precBits = DecimalDigits)
```

My R version is 4.0.3.

Comment: No, mine doesn't crash.  I'm able to get a result.  I'm also using 4.0.3.

Comment: I would suggest adding more information. For example `sessionInfo()`, your Rstudio version and what you have tried to fix the problem. Have you tried reinstalling R and/or Rstudio? (It should **not** be an Rstudio problem).

Comment: Added. Thank you!

Comment: I think this might be a translation problem from Rosetta.

Comment: might be worth asking on the `r-sig-mac@r-project.org` mailing list ...

Comment: Rstudio is surely irrelevant;  but R version of course is not.  There are quite a few known problems with M1 , notably missing Fortran compilers for the "native runtime".  However the Rosetta-emulation run time has been said to run flawlessly.  ... but please run R outside Rstudio in order get useful reports.   @DavidJ.Bosak: what is your `sessionInfo()`?  Are you on an M1 processor Mac, too?

Comment: @MartinMächler Thank you for your fruitful comments! Please see the added info. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinMächler No, I'm on Windows.  This question has changed a lot since I first commented. I don't think OS was mentioned in the original question.  Glad you are here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"R on the Mac"  has a dedicated mailing list
--> https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac/

The R Core developers are there, and they and others have been talking about R on the 'M1'  and related issues for many weeks now...
I'd be interested what they find about `Rmpfr` and if/when it's crashing R.
Yes, I'm interested as  `maintainer("Rmpfr")`

Comment: Thank you! As maintainer("Rmpfr"), would you please offer some hints about my question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322565/how-to-reduce-computation-time-with-rmpfrmpfr?

Comment: In the mean time, the archives of the R-SIG-Mac  mailing list also contain useful explanations and answers to the main question:   In short, the Rosetta2 software-emulation on the M1mac is not yet good enough, leading to the crash above for an `Rmpfr` which was *not* built (compiled, linked..) on the M1 itself.   This will be corrected by Simon Urbanek, *the* principal R-on-Mac maintainer.                                   Conclusion:  Wait a bit before moving all your R programming on the M1.

Comment: Links to relevant R-SIG-Mac archive threads:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2021-February/014002.html     and               https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2021-February/014007.html