# How to reduce computation time with Rmpfr::mpfr?

Tags: r, time, mpfr

The functions z1f and z1f.mpfr are the same besides the use of Rmpfr. However, the running time for z1f.mpfr is significantly higher than z1f even if I use smaller precBits than the default without mpfr. Codes below:

```
library(Rmpfr)

DecimalDigits=20

z1f.mpfr <- function(sample_freq, precBits = DecimalDigits)
{
  khat<-length(sample_freq)
  n<-sum(sample_freq)
  prod<-mpfr(rep(1,khat), precBits)
  zf<-mpfr(rep(0,n), precBits)
  for (v in 1:n){
    for (k in 1:khat){
      if (sample_freq[k]>=1){
        zf[v] = zf[v]+mpfr(sample_freq[k],precBits)/mpfr(n, precBits)*prod[k];
        prod[k] = prod[k]*(mpfr(1, precBits)-mpfr(sample_freq[k]-1, precBits)/mpfr(n-v, precBits));
      }
    }
  }
  return(zf)
}


z1f <- function(sample_freq)
{
  khat<-length(sample_freq)
  n<-sum(sample_freq)
  prod<-rep(1,khat)
  zf<-rep(0,n)
  for (v in 1:n){
    for (k in 1:khat){
      if (sample_freq[k]>=1){
        zf[v] = zf[v]+sample_freq[k]/n*prod[k];
        prod[k] = prod[k]*(1-(sample_freq[k]-1)/(n-v));
      }
    }
  }
  return(zf)
}

sample <- c(44, 30, 19, 10, 13, 7, 9, 6, 8, 8, 11, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

> system.time(z1f.mpfr(sample))
                      user                     system                    elapsed 
16.21299999999999386091076  0.02100000000000079580786 16.24599999999918509274721 

> system.time(z1f(sample))
                       user                      system                     elapsed 
0.0010000000000047748471843 0.0000000000000000000000000 0.0009999999992942321114242
```

My questions are two-fold:

1. Why will there be such a huge difference?
2. Can we offset the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: You already start wrongly:  precBits are *not*  decimal digits but binary bits !!

Comment: @MartinMächler Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the "profile" command to see where it is spending its time.  You are calling in "z1f.mpfr" functions that are computing to a certain digit precision.  This is very costly as  you can see in  your results.  If you really think you need the 20 digits, as opposed to what you get in floating point, then this is the price you pay.  You cannot optimize it since all the time is spent in the functions that you are calling.  You might want to get the source for those functions to understand how much code you are executing as oppose to just using floating point.  Functionality does not come for free and it you had used the profile you would have seen that you second function runs so fast it hardly registers much CPU usage.

Comment: How to run the "profile" command? Here's what I got:  > profile(z1f)
Error in UseMethod("profile") : 
  no applicable method for 'profile' applied to an object of class "function"
> profile(z1f(100))
Error in UseMethod("profile") : 
  no applicable method for 'profile' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: I typically use RStudio and the profiler associated with that.  I start the profiler, run the script and then stop the profiler and it produces the output.

Comment: If  you want to do it from the command line, use "Rprof" and "summaryRprof".

Comment: Also type "[r] how to profile a script" into Google to find other ways.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm the package maintainer: @Data Munger  is correct:  You pay quite a price if you don't use the very fast CPU-built in floating point arithmetic but the MPFR based arithmetic.    There's more to it -- extra inefficiency in my `Rmpfr` package that in principle could be eliminated.  For that I'd need collaborators who are good in R and C programming ...).

2nd:  You *really* should read the help pages of the important functions before using them ... in any R package.
In this case, you already start wrongly:  `precBits` are precision *bit*s  and bits are binary digits and *not* decimal digits ... so your `precBits = DecimalDigits` in your functions is ..sorry to say..  non-sense.

To go from bits to digits or back, you must multiply or divide  with / by  log10(2) ~= 0.3,  i.e.

```
bits <- ceiling(decimals / log10(2))
```

e.g.,

```r
> (digits <- 10*(1:4))
[1] 10 20 30 40
> (bits <- ceiling(digits / log10(2)))
[1]  34  67 100 133
>
```

... and yes, please use  `<-` : it's more friendly to all your code readers, including your future self ;-)